# Create the tasks dynamically that run some methods in queue using task parallelism?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

We have the scenario of creating the task dynamically (suppose 5 tasks) and  assign 5 tasks to some process(Suppose there are 15  method).
I want 5 task to take 5 method at a time and if any one the task is completed,it should take another method.

Can anyone provide the solution with example.

We have to put the methods in queue to take another method once any of the task is completed.

Comment: Try  this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789351(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Not very clear what you are asking. Also, this is not a coder service platform. You will have to show us what you tried so far and see if you can get help further on.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to implement any queues, you may use `Parallel.ForEach`.
That's exactly what it is designed for. The following example shows the simplest usage of `Parallel.ForEach`. `Stopwatch` is not a part of this functionality, it is only used to measure the time of execution.

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
List<Action> actions = new List<Action>();

actions.Add(() => { Thread.Sleep(1000); Console.WriteLine($"1 - {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}"); });
actions.Add(() => { Thread.Sleep(10000); Console.WriteLine($"2 - {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}"); });
actions.Add(() => { Thread.Sleep(3000); Console.WriteLine($"3 - {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}"); });
actions.Add(() => { Thread.Sleep(3000); Console.WriteLine($"4 - {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}"); });

sw.Start();
Parallel.ForEach(actions, new ParallelOptions
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2
}, action => action());
```

`MaxDegreeOfParallelism` specifies how many threads should be running your actions.

**If in the code above `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` is set to 1**, then these actions will be executed by a single thread:

```
1 - 1002
2 - 11002
3 - 14002
4 - 17003
```

**For `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` set to 2**, the output will be the following:

```
1 - 1029
3 - 3005
4 - 6009
2 - 11049
```

Note that it does not maintain the collection order. It is observable that at the begining, two threads took actions 1 and 3. Then, thread 1 took action 2, and thread 2 took action 4.

**For `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` equal to 4**, the output is obviously the following:

```
1 - 1029
3 - 3005
4 - 6009
2 - 11049
```

because 4 threads took all of actions at the same time, and executed this.

Comment: Thanks for the solution but in my case I want the actions with parameter. for eg List<Action<int>> actions = new List<Action<int>>();

Comment: @user3336576 just change this to Action<int> and use it in the same way.